# How to reset check status in html

Tags: html, angularjs

I have popup in  `HTML`

```
<div id="term_flags" class="term_flags">
        <div class="modal-users-content flagsContent">
            <div class="modal-users-header">
             <span class="close" ng-click="closeFlagsPopup()">&times;</span>
                <a> Check terminal flags </a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-flags-body">
                <div class="checkBoxes">
                    <div class="checkerDiv">
                        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model='reservedFlag' ng-click='changeReservedStatus(reservedFlag)' value="flag" ng-checked="reservedFlag"> Reserved
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkerDiv">
                        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model='seasonFlag' ng-click='changeSeasonStatus(seasonFlag)' value="flag" ng-checked="seasonFlag"> Season
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkerDiv">
                        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model='networkFlag' ng-click='changeNetworkStatus(networkFlag)' value="flag" ng-checked="networkFlag"> Network
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="saveFlags">
                    <a href="#/problems/zeroized"><button class="button button6" name="changeFlags" value="Change Flags" type="submit" ng-click="saveFlags(item.terminalId)"> Save <p> </button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this div's  `display` is `none` in the beginning. but some `ng-click` is called from outside of this div and  `display` is changed from `none` to `block` and initializes checkbox statuses in this angular function

```
$scope.changeFlagStatus = function(item)
    {
        $scope.reservedFlag=(item.reservedFlag=='T')?true:false;
        $scope.networkFlag=(item.networkFlag=='T')?true:false;
        $scope.seasonFlag=(item.seasonFlag=='T')?true:false;
        document.getElementById('term_flags').style.display = "block";
    }
```

everything is okay , but when i click on `reservedFlag` `changeReservedStatus(reservedFlag)` method was called and change `reservedFlag`'s checked status

```
$scope.changeReservedStatus = function(item) {
        $scope.reservedForSave=item;
    }
```

I saved this status in other variable and close my popup windows  `document.getElementById('term_flags').style.display=none`

when i open this popup window again my function `changeFlagStatus(item)` is called again and initializes my variables for checkbox correctly but my checkbox are incorrect checked .

In example when i opened my popup window first time my  variables after initialize were

```
$scope.reservedFlag=true;
$scope.networkFlag=false;
$scope.seasonFlag=true;
```

and my checkbox statuses were

```
reservedFlag = checked
networkFlag  = unchecked
seasonFlag   = checked
```

then i clicked on `reservedFlag` and changed his status from checked to unchecked and close my popup windows. 
then i opened it second time and `changeFlagStatus(item)` method is called again to initialize my variables again for checkbox statuses 
and i want to get

```
reservedFlag = checked
networkFlag  = unchecked
seasonFlag   = checked
```

again, but result is

```
reservedFlag = unchecked
networkFlag  = unchecked
seasonFlag   = checked
```

How can i get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angularjs won't work pretty good with $scope's properties for primitive variables when used again and again.
I would recommend you to declare an object to scope and set these flags as properties to this object.

```
$scope.flags = {};
$scope.changeFlagStatus = function(item)
{
$scope.flags.reservedFlag=(item.reservedFlag=='T')?true:false;
$scope.flags.networkFlag=(item.networkFlag=='T')?true:false;
$scope.flags.seasonFlag=(item.seasonFlag=='T')?true:false;
document.getElementById('term_flags').style.display = "block";
}
```

and the html part as

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model='flags.reservedFlag' ng-change='changeReservedStatus()' value="flag" ng-checked="flags.reservedFlag"> Reserved
```

Instead of ng-click, I would recommend to use ng-change because that is the event to be used with checkbox. If you use ng-change, the injection of the model as a parameter can be avoided which helps in utilizing angularjs's feature of 2-way binding.

You can add ng-true-value and ng-false-value to the checkbox with true and false to make it more easier to handle instead of ng-value.
I would write the html part like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model='flags.reservedFlag' ng-change='changeReservedStatus()' ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"> Reserved
```

Hope this will fix the issue.